# Can I use scrollview.bounces property of webview for handling webview scroll?

Tags: objective-c, webview, app-store, scrollview

I want to stop bounce in `webview`. can my app get rejected in appstore if I use following statement in my code?

```
self.viewController.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Thanks!

Comment: see my answer which will be accepted to App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ([[[UIDeice currentDevice] SystemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0)//iOS>=5.0
{
    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
}
else//iOS<5.0
{
    for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    {
       if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
         ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (webView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)]) {
    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
} else {
    for (id subview in webView.subviews) {
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            ((UIScrollView*)subview).bounces = NO;
        }
    }
}
```